# ActionScript Error- 1086: expecting a semicolon before left curly brace?

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am in the very beginning stages of creating my own online multiplayer trivia game and I was doing [this tutorial](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/flash_php_mysql2.htm) when I ran into a compile error (in title) in the actionscript associated with the 1st frame and the dynamic text field:

```
onClipEvent (load) {
  loadVariables("http://localhost/read.php?file=testfile", this, "GET");
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Using Flash CS5...is this code not compatible for CS3 or something? Any help would be appreciated, I have been trying to find out what I am doing wrong for like an hour! :)

Thanks!

Comment: This code is not AS3-valid. I think it's AS2. You should switch to another tutorial if you are willing to learn AS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are coding Actionscript 2 while your project is very likely set to be Actionscript 3. `onClipEvent` is an old heritage from Actionscript 1, so, that tutorial is outdated at best.

Your loading code (in AS3) should look more like this:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

// specify format as being variables
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleLoadComplete);

// load your data
loader.load(new URLRequest("foo.php")); 

function handleLoadComplete (e):void {
    trace(loader.data is URLVariables); // true
    trace(loader.data.valueFromYourData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the compile error! :) Now I just have to figure out how this works in tandem with PHP and mySQL, in the way I want it. Do that a different day, I have been up all night. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Flash, but as a Flex developer I would guess that your code is a function declaration (event handler). In strict ActionScript you would declare it like this:

```
protected function onClipEvent(load: Event): void {
  loadVariables("http://localhost/read.php?file=testfile", this, "GET");
}
```

Comment: Switched it out for your code, but still getting same error? *_*

Answer (score 0):

hm it looks like that tutorial has some mistakes, because I think you want to write "function onClipEvent(load)"  I'm surprised the fix splash suggested didn't change anything, either fixing things or at least generating a different error. Are you absolutely sure you ran it with the changed code?

Another probable cause for that error (most syntax errors actually) is a mistake in the code before it so we may need you to post more of your code then just that one function. Errors with brackets are often caused by not properly closing the previous code block (eg. accidentally deleting a bracket while pasting in new code):

```
function somethingOrOther() {
  blah

function onClipEvent(load) {  //error!
  stuff
}
```

Comment: That is the only actionscript I have on that frame so it shouldn't be possible that the missing brace is the issue? Ugh...lol

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing some thing wrong before these lines, may be **;** is missing 
just for test write it as

```
;onClipEvent (load)
```

Also share above lines
hopes that works

Comment: "Scene=Scene 1, layer=text, frame=1, Line 1 Clip events are permitted only for movie clip instances" is the result when running your give code?